# Is there any way to compress multiple lines in a single line in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I have constructed a big table in LaTeX, and since i am happy with it i was wondering if I can collapse it to a single line so that i dont have to scroll through the whole table code when i edit the rest of the document.

I  was wondering if there is a way to compress it to a single line, like you can do in R of STATA, and then expand it if I want to edit the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate file called, say, `very_long_table.tex` and paste the code of the table in it.

Then, in your .tex file you can `\input` this file.

For example:

`very_long_table.tex`

```
One & Other & One More \\
First & Second & Third
```

and your .tex file will be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\input{very_long_table}
\end{tabular}
\caption{A very, \emph{very} long table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```